# Multifactor auth in OAuth2 Password flow

Tags: multi-factor, oauth2

[This resource](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/password/) (and others) mention that OAuth2 Password flow doesn't provide mechanism for multi-factor authentication.

1. Does that mean other flows do?
2. How does MFA fit in the OAuth2 framework?
3. What is stopping you from using MFA with password flow?

OAuth2 always confuses me. I would appreciate answers and/or links to resources. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct.  The OAuth2 password flow does not support multifactor authentication because the only data it accepts is a username and password.

Most of the flows involve redirecting the user's browser to a login page that's part of the authentication provider.  After they log in, the authentication provider then redirects the user's browser back to the site that initiated the flow along with an access token they can use to prove they've authenticated.  Since the user is redirected to a login page controlled by the authentication provider, that page can authenticate them however it likes, using as many different factors as it wants.

The password flow is different though.  It doesn't involve browsers or login pages at all.  The client simply sends an HTTP POST request to the authentication provider that contains the user's username and password, and the authentication provider responds with an access token (or an error, if the credentials are incorrect).  The authentication provider could conceivably do some types of multifactor authentication that happen out-of-band (like an app-based push notification), but it would have to be done between when the client sent the request and when it responds.  HTTP requests tend to have timeouts on the order of a few seconds, so it would be very common for the request to time out before the user responded to the prompt, and there would be no way for the client to tell the user they need to check for one.  Overall it would be terrible UX.  Other types of MFA that require the user to enter a one-time code wouldn't work at all.